# Is it possible to trace changes to a UIView's frame?

Tags: ios, debugging, uiview, trace, lldb

For debugging purposes, is it possible to print out changes to view frames as a program runs, without stopping the debugging session?

Answer (score 4):

You can use LLDB breakpoint commands to do this.

```
(lldb) br set -S setFrame:
Breakpoint 4: 133 locations.
(lldb) br command add 4
Enter your debugger command(s).  Type 'DONE' to end.
> e (void) NSLog(@"frame change for %@:", $rdi)
> continue
> DONE
(lldb) c
Process 34698 resuming
```

This code accesses `self` in the x86_64 register `rdi`, but the correct register [depends on your architecture](https://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/02/04/inspecting-obj-c-parameters-in-gdb/). It does this by setting a breakpoint on any invocation of the selector `setFrame:` and running an LLDB evaluate command when the breakpoint is triggered. The breakpoint command then resumes execution after printing the frame.

This will output frame changes to any view in your app. Leave out the `continue` command if you want to enter the debugger when a frame changes.

Comment: Asking a question to answer it at exact the same moment?

Comment: @NikosM. Yes, this is a common thing to do: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: But why not to use KVO on `frame` property and just print it using usual `NSLog`?

Comment: @Azat Adding a KVO observer requires changing your code and recompiling. This method can be used in the middle of a debugger session, without a restart or recompile.

Comment: Can we restrict this to a particular view's frame changes ?

Comment: FYI on arm64, replace $rdi with $x0. As it didn't work on my end, I replaced `e (void) NSLog(@"frame change for %@:", $rdi)` with `po $x0`